# Spinning causes weird effects

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an observation loop, quite simply:

```
BlockingQueue<Object> q = new ArrayBlockingQueue(LENGTH);
while (true) {
    Object o = null;
    int spins = 0;

    // SPINNING LOOP
    while (spins++ < 1000)
        // Poll queue q, check if o is still null
    if (o == null)
        // Await for condition to be signaled

    // Inspect Object o
}
```

What I'm finding is: if the spin count is increased, you can insert items into the queue faster, but items can't be taken out as fast. But, if it is lowered, items are taken out faster at the cost of insertion speed. I am finding this by measuring the add method for insertion, and measuring the time between insertion and inspection for takeout time.

So in the example above, you can insert items quickly, but objects will be inspected slower.

Is there a possible explanation for that?

Comment: The proper answer is "never spin, use sleeps or waits."

Comment: Spinning is less expensive than having the thread sleep then wake up after an intermittent pause in the populator for the queue.

Comment: Less expensive for this thread. Disruptive for other thread scheduling. Bad Practice except in VERY special circumstances, and most of those shouldn't be being coded in Java. And if you absolutely must spin, have the decency to code a yield in the loop's body.

Comment: Did that and fixed both problems. I am totally shocked. Thanks.

Comment: Homework assignment: Understand why the change fixed the problems. Think about what happens with other threads while a tight spin is in progress... or more accurately, what isn't happening.

Comment: I would assume that a spinning thread burns a single core while other threads that could be doing work are waiting for the context switch?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UqRN2F5u According to this test, the thread that gets the most is the 0 index thread, which "spins" until we get to 100M. All the other threads have a lower amount, especially the extra thread which can't use the processor.